# How to drop null field while unmarshalling the xml to java object with jaxb

Tags: java

I want to drop null field while unmarshalling response (xml response) using jaxb

for example while unmarshalling the below  xml response usimg jaxb

Customer [name=null, age=20, id=100]

is there any to omit null field using jaxb   i am expecting below response

Customer [ age=20, id=100]

is there any way other i can achieve this?

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}


XML RESPONSE


        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <customer id="100">
        <age>29</age>
    </customer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce what happens:

```
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setAge(20);
    c.setName(null);
    c.setId(100);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(c, sw);

    String xmlString = sw.toString();
    System.out.print(xmlString);
```

Returns:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><customer id="100"><age>20</age></customer>
```

which looks like what you aspire to receive.
Could you please provide how you process the XML when the null field is printed?